# How to stop/control events triggered by AWS S3 on Object upload for invoking AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm currently uploading a file into AWS S3 Bucket(B1) with 250 MB size & 1 Million records. This triggers a Lambda (L1 - 1.5GB, 3 Mins) which reads this file & grouping the records with some criteria & writing about 25K files into S3 again on the different bucket(B2).

Now, notification event configured on Bucket (B2) generates 25K events(requests) to different Lambda (L2 - 512MB, 2Mins, Concurrency-2). This Lambda calls a Java-based micro-service which makes an entry into DB after processing which takes about 1-2 seconds for each call.

The problem here is, Once 2nd Lambda (L2) is triggered, there's no way to stop it. It runs for hours & not receiving any other event for the same lambda until processing all events completely & I've no control over S3 events triggered already.

Can someone please explain how events triggered on S3 upon file upload being processed (architecture) on Amazon S3 & how to get fine-grained control over S3 events triggered?

Is there anything I can do on AWS Lambda side to stop S3 events triggered already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think setting a notification event on `B2` is the best option when you are writing 25K objects at a time. I think process can be simplified.

- `Lambda L1` that writes 25K objects in `B2` can create an array of object keys being written and put that in `B2`. Make sure it is written in a separate folder and notification event is set on that folder and not in the location where 25K files being written.
- `L2` will be triggered when you write file containing keys of 25K objects which it can pass to your `microservice`.

Another option using SNS

- `Lambda L1` that writes 25K objects in `B2` can create an array of object keys being written and publish it to an SNS Topic. SNS message size is 256 KB which is enough for your use case
- You `mircoservice` can subscribe to SNS Topic to receive the object keys and make entries in the DB